# How can I implement the new iPad-like landscape mode on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

Apple has introduced a new iPad-like split view in landscape mode for iPhone plus, which help users take advantage of their larger screen.

I have designed an universal iOS app which uses UISplitViewController to show detail and master view in iPad, and uses UINavigationViewController to show the TableView in iPhone.

Now that we have iPhone plus, how can I implement the new iPad-like landscape view while I am using UINavigationViewController as the main structure in iPhone.

Comment: You use `UISplitViewController` for both the iPad and iPhone under iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit" video on https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

De basic idea is that the split view controller is used on iPhone and iPad. But when it detects that the device has a "Compact" horizontal size class it pushes the detailview on top of the master view, whereas with a "Regular" size class it shows the detailview next to the master view.